# Sphere Online Judge(SPOJ) - SIGSEGV Error in code

Tags: arrays, matrix, segmentation-fault

So I had a task:
There is a rectangular matrix X containing integers, consisting of m rows and n columns. The number of rows and columns can not be more than 100. Write a program that finds the matrix product: (Xtransposed * X). In the first line of input there is an integer m ∈ [1;100] specifying the number of rows of matrix X. In the second line of input there is an integer n ∈ [1;100] specifying the number of columns of matrix X. The next m lines contain n integers, from the range [-100;100], separated by a space, specifying the elements of the X matrix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m, n;
    cin >> m >> n;
    vector<vector<int> > X(m, vector<int> (n));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> X[i][j];
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int> > Xtransposed(n, vector<int> (m));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Xtransposed[j][i] = X[i][j];
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int> > result(m, vector<int> (m));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                result[i][j] += Xtransposed[i][k] * X[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << result[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I read that the program tries to access unallocated memory space that the process cannot access but I have no clue what is it all about (since programm works)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
   vector<vector<int> > result(n, vector<int> (n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                result[i][j] += Xtransposed[i][k] * X[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << result[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```